# Syntax error in query expression strUserPassword

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

```
 If Me.Text14.Value = DLookup("strUserPassword]", "tblusers", _
     "[UserID]=" & Me.Combo0.Value) Then
```

Can anyone help me see where Im going wrong?

[image]

Comment: @ Dale  - ms access

Comment: In future please just tag the RDBMS of interest.

Comment: I doubt you in the table have a field named _strUserPassword_.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Me.Text14.Value = DLookup("[strUserPassword]", "tblusers", _ "[UserID]=" & Me.Combo0.Value)
```

`[` is missing before `strUserPassword`

Comment: @Dale..thankyou. Below is my code in full. pls assist.

Comment: 'Check value of password in tblusers to see if this
    'matches value chosen in combo box

    If Me.Text14.Value = DLookup("strUserPassword", "tblusers", _
    "[UserID]=" & Me.Combo0.Value) Then
    
     UserID = Me.Combo0.Value
     
    'Close logon form and open splash screen
    
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogon", acSaveNo
        DoCmd.OpenForm "splashscreen"

    Else
      MsgBox "Password Invalid. Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, _
            "Invalid Entry!"
        Me.Text14.SetFocus
    End If